# Una duda de hexadecimal y c

Tags: c, ascii

El ejercicio que se plantea para hacer en C es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mas o menos el planteamiento lo tengo claro la tabla representa los valores de tab[] en hexadecimal y a la derecha su espresion en ASCII, como nos dice que lo hagamos segun el ejemplo y como 1Byte son 2 caracteres de hexadecimal debo suponer que cada elemento del array debe ocupar 4Bytes (No se si esto es por convenio o alguna otra razon pues segun tengo entendido int ocupa 2Bytes en C, asi que supongo que sera por que asi lo quiere hacer el que plantea el problema), bien pues mi duda es la siguiente: Segun veo para representar los elementos de tab[] se usan solo dos caracteres de hexadecimal, es decir, (N1)*16^1 + (N2)*16^0, por tanto el maximo que puedo escribir es 0xff = 255,
si en el array escribo un numero mayor a 255 cual es la forma de representarlo aqui? pues supongo que los otros 3Bytes restantes estan para algo no?

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta para pegar el código como texto, y no como imagen? Pensemos en quienes están en dispositivos con pantallas chicas, quienes tienen pantallas chicas o quienes odian ver ese fondo negro y esa combinación de colores. La idea es que alguien que quiera responderte pueda copiar tu código, probarlo, llevarlo a la respuesta... intenta hacer que alguien que quiera responderte tenga una tarea más sencilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el tipo int se definió como una *palabra* en las micro arquitecturas 8086, 80286, no obstante desde el 80386, int es por defecto una *doble palabra*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Basicamente lo que te piden es imprimir líneas de `16B` en 2 columnas, la primera columna es la representación en hexadecimal en grupos de `2B` mientras que la segunda columna es la representación en ascii.

El pseucódigo sería el siguiente

```
void
print_memory (const void *addr, size_t size)
{
  for(cada byte en [addr, addr + size])
   {
      imprimir byte en hex
      if(se ha imprimido 2B)
        {
          imprimir espacio
        }

      if(se han imprimido 16B)
        {
          imprimir los 16B anteriores en ascii
          imprimir salto de linea
        }

   }
   imprimir en forma alineada los ascii de la línea incompleta
   imprimir salto de linea
}
```

La implementación es algo trivial

**print_memory.c**

```
#include <ctype.h> // isprint
#include <stdio.h>  // printf
#include <stdlib.h> // size_t

#define LINE_IN_BYTES         0x10 
#define WORD_IN_BYTES         2
#define HEX_DIGIT_PER_CHAR    2

#define IS_ODD(x) (x % 2 == 1)

              void print_memory (const void*, size_t);
static        void print_ascii (const void*, size_t);
static inline void print_spaces (size_t);

int
main (void)
{
  int tab[10] = {0, 23, 150, 255, 12, 16, 21, 42};
  char m[17] = "Hola mundo";

  print_memory (tab, sizeof(tab));
  print_memory (m, sizeof(m));  

  return 0;
}

void
print_memory (const void *addr, size_t size)
{
  size_t i;
  size_t resto;
  const unsigned char *c;

  if (addr == NULL)
      return; 

  for (i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
      c = (addr + i - 1);
      printf ("%02hhx", *c);

      if (i % WORD_IN_BYTES == 0)
        {
          putchar (' ');
        }

      if (i % LINE_IN_BYTES == 0)
        {
          print_ascii (c - LINE_IN_BYTES + 1, LINE_IN_BYTES);
          printf ("\n");
        }
    }

    if ((resto = size % LINE_IN_BYTES) > 0) // falta ascii que imprimir
      {
        print_spaces ((HEX_DIGIT_PER_CHAR + 0.5) * (LINE_IN_BYTES - resto)); // rellena lo faltante
        if(IS_ODD (resto))
            putchar (' '); // alinea a palabra 
        print_ascii (c - resto + 1, resto);
        printf ("\n");
      }
}


static void 
print_ascii (const void *addr, size_t size)
{
  size_t i;
  const unsigned char *c;

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      c = (addr + i);
      if (isprint (*c))
        putchar (*c);
      else
        putchar ('.');
    } 
}

static inline 
void 
print_spaces (size_t size)
{
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      putchar(' ');   
    }
}
```

Compilarlo

```
$ gcc print_memory.c -o print_memory -Wall -Werror; ./print_memory | cat -e
0000 0000 1700 0000 9600 0000 ff00 0000 ................$
0c00 0000 1000 0000 1500 0000 2a00 0000 ............*...$
0000 0000 0000 0000                     ........$
486f 6c61 206d 756e 646f 0000 0000 0000 Hola mundo......$
00                                      .$
```

**Observaciones:**
No te preocupes por el *endianness*, puesto que no varia mucho, ya que ANSI C especifica que los elementos en un array deben almacenarse conforme se declaren, siendo el primer elemento del array el de menor dirección en memoría.

Tu arreglo

```
               MAYOR

    0         4
    ===========
              0      tab + 36
    -----------
              0      tab + 32
    -----------
             42      tab + 28
    -----------
             21      tab + 24
    -----------
             16      tab + 20
    -----------
             12      tab + 16
    -----------
            255      tab + 12   
    -----------
            150      tab +  8
    -----------
             23      tab +  4
    -----------
              0      tab +  0
    ===========        
MENOR
```

Sea cuál sea el *endianness*, la anterior figura no cambia.

## Little endian

La anterior figura para little endian sería la siguiente

```
               MAYOR

    0         4 
    ===========
    0x0000 0000      tab + 36
    -----------
    0x0000 0000      tab + 32
    -----------
    0x2A00 0000      tab + 28
    -----------
    0x1500 0000      tab + 24
    -----------
    0x1000 0000      tab + 20
    -----------
    0x0C00 0000      tab + 16
    -----------
    0xFF00 0000      tab + 12   
    -----------
    0x9600 0000      tab +  8
    -----------
    0x1700 0000      tab +  4
    -----------
    0x0000 0000      tab +  0
    ===========        
MENOR
```

## Big endian

```
               MAYOR

    0         4 
    ===========
    0x0000 0000      tab + 36
    -----------
    0x0000 0000      tab + 32
    -----------
    0x0000 002A     tab + 28
    -----------
    0x0000 0015      tab + 24
    -----------
    0x0000 0010      tab + 20
    -----------
    0x0000 000C      tab + 16
    -----------
    0x0000 00FF      tab + 12   
    -----------
    0x0000 0096      tab +  8
    -----------
    0x0000 0017      tab +  4
    -----------
    0x0000 0000      tab +  0
    ===========        
MENOR
```

Comment: Gracias por una respuesta tan aclaratoria, habia conceptos de los que no tenia constancia como el endianess, solo para confirmar que mi duda esta aclarada , a la hora de almacenar cualquier dato en hexadecimal se almacena byte a byte (los dos caracteres de hexadecimal) segun cada criterio, en big endian es por asi decirlo el "orden clasico" de escribir un numero en su base en este caso : 16^8 + 16^7 + ... + 16^1 + 16^0 en cambio little endian invierte en bytes el orden es decir que quedaria: (16^1 + 16^0) + (16^3 + 16^2) + ... + (16^8 + 16^7). es correcto?

Comment: @Latiagertrutis, el endianness sólo aplica a los bytes no a los bits, por ejemplo *0xEC* representado en little es *0xEC*, y en big *0xEC*, cómo puedes ver en ambos casos es igual, porque es un sólo byte, el endianness afecta únicamente el orden de los bytes en memoria. Así pues *0x EC FF* se representaría en memoria como *0x FF EC* y *0xEC FF* para little y big endian respectivamente (el byte en la izquierda tiene una dirección de memoria menor que el de la derecha)

Answer (score 1):

> No se si esto es por convenio o alguna otra razon pues segun tengo
>   entendido int ocupa 2Bytes en C.

Lo que te retorne `sizeof(int)` depende del compilador, pero actualmente es mucho mas comun que `int` tenga un tamaño de 4 bytes, esto serian 8 digitos hexadecimales.

> Si en el array escribo un numero mayor a 255 cual es la forma de
>   representarlo aqui?

Si te fijas en lo que retorna la funcion `print_memory` te daras cuenta de que a cada elemento de `tab` le corresponden 8 digitos en hexadecimal, es decir, 0 sera impreso como `0000 0000`, 255 sera impreso como `ff00 0000`, ¿que pasa si nos pasamos de 255?, pues nada, por ejemplo 256 seria impreso como `1000 0000`, para explicar porque sucederia esto de forma mas clara realize este programa que hace casi lo mismo que el que muestras en el enunciado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_memory(int *array, size_t size) {
  int i, times = size / sizeof(int);

  for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    printf("%08x ", array[i]);

    if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0)
      printf("\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  int tab[10] = {256, 23, 150, 255, 12, 16, 21, 42};

  print_memory(tab, sizeof(tab));

  return 0;
}
```

Si lo ejecutamos obtendremos:

```
00000100 00000017 00000096 000000ff
0000000c 00000010 00000015 0000002a
00000000 00000000
```

Como ves 255 es representado por `000000ff`, pero en el programa original se imprime en [Little Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), por lo tanto queda `ff000000`, es decir 256 que seria representado por `00000100` en el programa original se mostraria como `10000000`, el problema de esto es que se origina confusion, ya que no podrias saber si `10000000` representa 256, 1 o 12 (si te fijas en tu enunciado 12 tambien se imprime como `10000000`)

**En resumen**

El programa del enunciado hace lo mismo que el que puse mas arriba, pero imprime los numeros hexadecimales en formato little endian, y para la parte de los caracteres solo faltaria imprimir lo que estos numeros representan en codigo ASCII.